# Should I include a dummy variable for groups with few observations?

Tags: regression, econometrics, overfitting, categorical-encoding

I am doing some analysis of US Senate races and in my regression I'm wondering if I should include a (party X state) indicator variable that essentially measures the average vote for the two major parties in each state.

The issue is I have 424 observations, so there would only be about 4 observations per dummy on average, and some of the party/state pairings only have 1 observation. I then also filter the data for some analysis, dropping observations to 244 total and dropping ~20 party/state pairings completely. Should I include the set of dummies, or will this cause problems with estimating my independent variables of interest?

For what it's worth I also have data that assigns the Cook PVI for the given state and year, or essentially the state's average political lean, so I can use that in lieu of the dummies (or both). Additionally, my independent variables of interest actually got more statistically significant after adding the set of dummies.

First post here. Please let me know what you think, thanks.